# Request destroyed before initialization

Tags: servlet-listeners

I'm doing experiment with ServletRequestListener. I get the following output when i run the program. Some requests destroyed before initialized. why is that?

```
New request arrived to server :/projeDB/
Request destroyed : /projeDB/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml;jsessionid=2CDF29CD90D3EB1143D06AACAF7BA387
Request destroyed : /projeDB/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml;jsessionid=2CDF29CD90D3EB1143D06AACAF7BA387
Request destroyed : /projeDB/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml;jsessionid=2CDF29CD90D3EB1143D06AACAF7BA387
New request arrived to server :/projeDB/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml;jsessionid=2CDF29CD90D3EB1143D06AACAF7BA387
Request destroyed : /projeDB/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.xhtml;jsessionid=2CDF29CD90D3EB1143D06AACAF7BA387
Request destroyed : /projeDB/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml
New request arrived to server :/projeDB/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml;jsessionid=2CDF29CD90D3EB1143D06AACAF7BA387
New request arrived to server :/projeDB/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.xhtml;jsessionid=2CDF29CD90D3EB1143D06AACAF7BA387
New request arrived to server :/projeDB/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml;jsessionid=2CDF29CD90D3EB1143D06AACAF7BA387
New request arrived to server :/projeDB/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml
Request destroyed : /projeDB/javax.faces.resource/images/ui-icons_38667f_256x240.png.xhtml
New request arrived to server :/projeDB/javax.faces.resource/images/ui-icons_38667f_256x240.png.xhtml
```

My ServletRequestListener :

```
public class RequestListener implements ServletRequestListener {
    @Override
    public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        System.out.println("New request arrived to server :" + ((HttpServletRequest) sre.getServletRequest()).getRequestURI())  ; 
    }

    @Override
    public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
        System.out.println("Request destroyed : " + ((HttpServletRequest) sre.getServletRequest()).getRequestURI());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't you switched the print statements in the methods? You print that the request has been destroyed in the `requestInitialized()` method and vice versa.

Comment: i would like to know why client requests those resources. How is client aware of that resources are missing? I am using primefaces 5.2 tags on my page.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The invocation of the ServletRequestListener handlers is bound to the life cycle of the request object. When a client will send a request to a server resource is specific to the responses sent by the server and the way the client treats them. Are you saying you don't understand why the client sends a request to

/projeDB/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml;jsessionid=2CDF29CD90D3EB1143D06AACAF7BA387

for example? Use HttpWatch if your client is a browser and you will see all you need there

Comment: yes that's what i want to know. Does server inform the client with the response which says you will need those resources to see the page completely? if so, which part of the response holds the information about future resources will be needed by client?

Comment: If the client has to display something, the server responds with an HTML page. This HTML page contains resources - static images, dynamic contents, client-side code (JavaScript), etc. When the contents that has to be displayed is not available directly in the HTML code, it has to be fetched from somewhere. For example, when you specify the CSS style of your page, you also add the URL from which the client has to take it. This is how it knows what resources to request - by going through the links in the HTML code and determining which of them it has to contact